# How to enter sudo password if there are several commands on the same line in bash console

Tags: bash

I wanted to run my Python script and then turn off my computer completely. After a while, I saw a screen on which sudo asked me for a password, which means that My computer was turned on for a few days just like that.
I tried this, but it not worked:

```
sudo ls
python3 test.py && sudo shutdown now
```

So how can I run sudo with a password in one command line? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could reverse it and execute the script explicitly as your normal user

```
sudo sh -c 'sudo -u $SUDO_USER test.py && shutdown now'
```

Comment: You can use the variable `"$SUDO_USER"` to access the original user's name. That way you can eliminate the place holder `{{your user}}`.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo` can be configured to cache your password; but the simple and robust solution is to `sudo` the entire command line.

```
sudo sh -c ' ls; 
    python3 test.py && shutdown now'
```

Notice that this will run `python3` as root, too, though. Generally you want to minimize the privileges for each command. If you have the privileges, of course, you could use `su` to run Python as your regular user from the privileged context.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution here: https://superuser.com/a/67766

```
$echo <password> | sudo -S <command>
```

Just use pipe and -S key, for me looks like:

```
python3 test.py && echo <password> | sudo -S shutdown now
```

Comment: Please note that this will put your plaintext password in `.bash_history`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$echo <password> | sudo -S <command>
```

and then clear bash history:

```
cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history
```